# How to parse Azure SQL table rows as JSON to trigger Azure Function in Datafactory?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to take in the input Azure SQL dataset and use this as the request body for my HTTP triggered Azure Function, but unsure of the best practice here.

The Azure Function accepts a POST request, which is a JSON array of data/rows.

I can copy from the table into a JSON file in Blob, but unsure how to get this into the Azure Function task in Data Factory:

Example input table:

| Index | Country | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | England | 21 |
| 2 | Scotland | 22 |
| 3 | Wales | 23 |

Needs to be a JSON array for the body of the Azure Function:

```
[{"Index":1,"Country":England, "Age":21}, 
 {"Index":2, "Country":Scotland", "Age":22},
 {"Index":3, "Country":Wales", "Age":23}]
```

I'm guessing I need to use some dynamic parameters and/or something in the body part of the Azure Function?

[image: Azure function body?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are copying the json in blob.
A blob storage triggers can be used.  This trigger once some data is copied in the blob storage.
You can then configure the function for further functionality.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?msclkid=a8767813b65611ec8c45f0b6d842754b&tabs=in-process,extensionv5&pivots=programming-language-javascript) to create a blob trigger function.